# How to extract regex out of string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have list of strings and need to find regex followed by those. for example I  have 10 strings in which 3 are emails, 2 are numbers, 5 are alphanumeric.I don't want to maintain fixed list of regex and keep matching strings and tell user about their data.
At least if I could find general patterns followed by them.
I am searching for some libraries in Java.

Comment: example input/ouput expected please

Answer (score 0):

So.... depending on what language you're implementing this in, it could be easy or somewhat close to impossible.

To match a string, you can typically just do

```
/(\w)+/g which will eat all characters
```

If you want to match an alphanumeric string (again, breaking on space) you could do something like

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])+
```

Matching an email is EXTREMELY complex, but the rule implemented in HTML5 looks something like this (though it can miss some international characters, and isn't 100% accurate, it's around 99% accurate)

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*)/i
```

If you have something more specific you're trying to do, feel free to comment.

Comment: The language I want this in Java. the problem is I don't want to specify lot of regexes and let the user know the most probable regex of string. If i can find any library which takes string as input and gives me most specific regex as possible for that String. I can understand that for a string there are lot of regexes which satisfy that string. but just giving a try if some library exists which can solve my purpose.

Comment: That's a bit of a weird usage.... There are regex builders online, but in theory the quickest way to match any string is always going to be a combination of \w \W and maybe some \d \D \s and \S.   To make it intelligently build regexes is really difficult.   example, the string "abc123" would match the regex ([a-c]{0,3}\d+), \w+{0,3}\d+, \w+, abc123, .*(?=.*\w)3, etc. etc. etc.   The idea of how you build a regex is REALLY rooted in what you need to capture and what the pattern is for your specific string, which is normally decided based on how the string is generated more than regex itself